# Jest TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test the onSubmit method, however im getting this error.

> TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

I'm referencing this blog tutorial

https://medium.com/@aghh1504/6-testing-react-components-using-jest-and-enzyme-b85db96fa1e3

i referenced another question but no answer

[e.preventDefault is not a function - Jest React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185000/e-preventdefault-is-not-a-function-jest-react)

**App.test.tsx**

```
describe('Should test onSubmit method',() => {
  it('should test onSubmit method', ()=>{
    const component = shallow(<App/>)
    const preventDefault = jest.fn();
    const items = ['Learn react', 'rest', 'go out'];
    component.setState({
     currentTask:"test-task",
     tasks:[...items, 'test-task']
    })

    component.find('form').simulate('submit', preventDefault);
    expect(preventDefault).toBeCalled();

  })
})
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// we need an interface to be able to use the state properties, if not error.
// the same rule applies when using props
// so here we call Istate
interface IState {
  currentTask: string;
  tasks: Array<string>;
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, IState>{
  constructor(props: {}){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTask: "",
      tasks:[]
    }
  }

  // when using e.preventDefault in typescript, or any paramater, it has to be followed
 //  by the following any, array, string, etc. in this case we use any

  handleSubmit(e: any){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      currentTask: "",
      tasks: [...this.state.tasks, this.state.currentTask]
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.tasks)
    })


  }

  onChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      currentTask: e.target.value
    })

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className="sampleh1">React Typescript Todo</h1>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
           <input value={this.state.currentTask} type="text" placeholder="enter a todo"
            onChange={this.onChange}/>
           <button type="submit"> Add Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: try this: `component.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault });` Object containing preventDefault

Comment: ok let me give this a shot.

Comment: @randal what about `.invoke()` function

Comment: Not working for `invoke()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing mockEvent object as second argument.

```
component.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault });
```

Comment: the solution in your comment worked. It passes now. But this edit gives me an error.

Comment: Right, this is the same code, twisted a bit to be more expressive and extendable in case you need more properties on the event Mock.

Comment: what about   `component.setState({
     currentTask:"test-task",
     tasks:[...items, 'test-task']
    })` ?

Comment: please edit it back to the way it was, so i can mark this as an answer, im getting an error now.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I would have to try out how it differs.

Comment: this is the error i got, if your curious `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`

Comment: this(as in your current edit) passes, however would you write this handleSubmit test differently ?

Comment: Ah you just need to store the reference of the jest.fn() on which you can do `expect`

Comment: can you make an edit, so i can have a better idea. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193804/discussion-between-rikin-and-randal).

Comment: @Rikin what about `.invoke()` function

Answer (score 3):

If you using Jest

```
form.simulate(`submit`, {preventDefault: jest.fn()});
```

or just an empty function if you don't

```
form.simulate(`submit`, {preventDefault: () => {}});
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `simulate` is the mock event that gets passed to the handler when you call `onSubmit`, so it has to be in the form of the event object that handler expects:

```
component.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault });
```

Likewise, if you're going to test your `onChange` function, you'll need to pass a mock event with a `target/value` as the 2nd argument to `simulate`:

```
component.find('input').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'todo' } });
```

Comment: yeah the onchange method is tested, thanks though. i had a similar logic to yours for the onchange method.

Comment: this logic works, thanks . @rikkin gave me this solution first, but thanks for explaining your logic.